# Count all the revisions for all files in a git project

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

Is there a git command that can output for every file in a project something like this or similar to it:

```
20 file1
43 file2 etc.
```

I'm interested to see how many times was each file modified by any author, not just for a specific one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a sorted list of all files and the number of commits that modifies them:

```
git log --pretty='' --name-only | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

- `--pretty=''`: do not output commit information (`''`)
- `--name-only`: print name of changed files only
- `sort | uniq -c`: group file names and count number of occurrences (= number of commits modifying the file)
- `sort -n`: numerical sort by number of modifications

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank You!